# How do I upgrade a composer package after having constrained the version?

Tags: composer-php

Suppose that for stability reasons, I've constrained the version of a particular package in `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "foo/bar": "~3.2.6",
}
```

I am now ready to upgrade `foo/bar` to version 4.

What is the correct workflow to do this?

Should I edit the `composer.json` file by hand and run one of `composer install` or `update`? Or should I do `composer require foo/bar 4`?

Comment: Yes,  you just have to execute `composer require foo/bar:~4`.

Answer (score 1):

> **composer require vendor/package:version**

like :

```
composer require foo/bar:^4.0.0
```